# Verify Divergence theorem for $z= 4-x^2-y^2$

Tags: integration

I have to verify the divergence theorem for $F(x,y,z)=(2z,x,y^2)$ being V the solid region between $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and the plane XY.

Like $div \space F=0$ then $\int_{V} div F =0$

However when I compute $\int_S F. N dS$ I have that it value is $4 \pi$ :

I have chosen the parametrization $\rho(r,\alpha)=(r cos \alpha, r sin \alpha, 4-r^2)$ for $\alpha \in [0, 2Pi]$ and $r \in [0,2]$ and have:

$\int_S F. N dS= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2} (2(4-r^2),r cos(\alpha),r^2 sin^2(\alpha)).(2r^2 cos(\alpha).2 r^2 sin(\alpha),r) dr d\alpha=4\pi$

Where have I been wrong?

Comment: You forgot the flux through the base circle on the $xy $ plane

Comment: i computed it and is $4 \pi$ then the flux across the surface is $8 \pi$??

Comment: I believe one of them should be $-4\pi$. Make sure your normal vector points inwards; it affects the sign of the final integral